# What are the advantages of using offsets in vkCmdBindVertexBuffers vkCmdDraw?

Tags: offset, vulkan, vertex-buffer

In the vulkan, I have a vertex buffer which stores 6 vertices. The first 3 belong to one triangle and the other 3 to another. Each vertex has two floats specifying the x and y positions and another 3 for the rgb.

If I'd like to draw only one triangle, it seems I can achieve the same result by either specifying an offset of 3*5*sizeof(float) to poffsets of vkCmdBindVertexBuffers or alternatively specify firstVertex as 3 to vkCmdDraw.

Are their any advantages to either of the methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not obvious there's an advantage either way in the scenario you describe. On some architectures, if you're doing a bunch of back-to-back draw calls that use attributes from the same `VkBuffer`, using `firstVertex` instead of having to call `vkCmdBindVertexBuffers` between each draw might have lower overhead.

The functional difference is that with the offset, you're changing where "vertex 0" is, i.e. adjusting the the logical start of the vertex buffer. If you were using `vkCmdDrawIndexed`, an index value of 0 would refer to the vertex at that offset. In the vertex shader, the `VertexId` builtin variable would be 0.

By using firstVertex, you're saying that the logical vertex buffer starts at offset 0 into the `VkBuffer`, but that you want to draw geometry starting from some vertex not at the beginning of the buffer. The vertex shader would see `VertexId` values in the range [`firstVertex` .. `firstVertex+vertexCount-1`].

So if you have a large `VkBuffer` that you just append different unrelated/independent meshes to, especially if they have different layouts, you might want to just use the offset as you bind each one: you've essentially got different logical vertex buffers stored in a single `VkBuffer`. Or alternately, if you have a vertex layout with non-interleaved attributes (e.g. position in one "binding", other attributes in another "binding") but want to store them in the same `VkBuffer`, you'd need to bind the same `VkBuffer` as two different vertex buffers, but with different offsets.

On the other hand, if for example you collect dynamically-generated mesh geometry into a vertex buffer each frame, you might want to just bind the vertex buffer once and then use `firstVertex` to issue the draw call for each mesh. Or if you need to use `VertexId` for some calculation (e.g. indexing into a storage buffer) you'd want to use `firstVertex` so each vertex gets the expected `VertexId` value.

Comment: "*On some architectures, ... might have lower overhead.*" But if there are no architectures where the other way might have lower overhead, then it seems to me that this is a clear advantage. There's one method of rendering which will never be *worse* than the other.

Answer (score 0):

The (byte) offset allows you to interleave the vertex data with other kind of data, which might not be aligned at `sizeof(vertex)`.